# How to increase OpenLDAP DN max length?

Tags: ldap, openldap

The maximum length of an OpenLDAP DN seems to be 255 characters.

How can this value can be increased?

Answer (score 0):

yes, dn max length is 255.

microsoft suggests to shorten the OU name...

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc756101(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN